# show custom category posts from a custom post type

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to show posts from a **Custom Post Type** (documents) that has a custom **Taxonomy** (subject) with two categories, each category page should have its own posts. But when I open any of these categories page, I get all posts from this Custom Post Type.

I created a file **taxonomy-subject.php** with below code:

```
$args = array( 'post_type'      => 'documents',
               'posts_per_page' => 20 );
$terms = get_terms( 'subject', array (
                             'hide_empty' => 0,)
                  );               
$loop = new WP_Query( $args, $term );
             while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
// content
```

so where the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should need to do any custom querying on `taxonomy-subject.php`, just use the normal [loop api](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). WordPress will build a query for you.

As for your question:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'documents',
  'posts_per_page' => 20,
);
```

`WP_Query` doesn't take a second argument to its constructor. All its seeing is the arguments above. You're asking WP_Query for 20 posts from the document post type. Its giving them to you. If you want posts from a specific term, you'll need to tell it that [with a taxonomy parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'documents',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'tax_query' => array(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'subject',
        'terms' => get_queried_object_id(),
    )),
));
```

`get_queried_object_id` should return the term ID on `taxonomy-subject.php`, you'll need to use some other code if this loop is being used elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but tax_query gave an empty list. Do I need to relate the custom taxonomy to the custom post type? I already done that when registered the post type with taxonomies parameter. Is there more to be done?